# Failed to resolve "Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, react-scripts

I am trying to run a react-native app, but I fail to run the app successfully because of some or the other error.

I used [React-Native environment setup docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) and installed dependencies in my mobile-app folder using `yarn install` command. Then, I tried to run the app using `npm run android`. The error stack given in Node.js with node **v18.15.0** was:

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at stableHash (C:\Code\potato-disease\mobile-app\node_modules\metro-cache\src\stableHash.js:19:8)
    at Object.getCacheKey (C:\Code\potato-disease\mobile-app\node_modules\metro-config\node_modules\metro-transform-worker\src\index.js:647:7)
    at getTransformCacheKey (C:\Code\potato-disease\mobile-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\getTransformCacheKey.js:32:19)
    at new Transformer (C:\Code\potato-disease\mobile-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:180:28)
    at C:\Code\potato-disease\mobile-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:58:29
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:509:9) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Seeing other StackOverFlow answers to a similar error, I have tried to update `react-scripts` and `start` parameters in my `package.json` file, but the error persists. Some answers recommended to downgrade Node version to 16.0.0. I did that too, but after using `npm run android`, I got this error in my gitbash terminal (no error msgs in Node.js this time):

```
npm WARN cli npm v9.5.0 does not support Node.js v16.0.0. You should probably upgrade to a
npm WARN cli newer version of node as we can't make any promises that npm will work with this
npm WARN cli version. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 ||
npm WARN cli ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

> mlDemo@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 926 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app
Reading env from: .env

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
7 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\hp\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.react\react-native\0.71.0-rc.0\7a7f5a0af6ebd8eb94f7e5f7495e9d9684b4f543\react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar.
         > Java heap space

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\hp\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.react\react-native\0.71.0-rc.0\7a7f5a0af6ebd8eb94f7e5f7495e9d9684b4f543\react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar.
         > Java heap space

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s

    at makeError (C:\Code\potato-disease\mobile-app\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Code\potato-disease\mobile-app\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Code\potato-disease\mobile-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Code\potato-disease\mobile-app\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Also, I used `yarn install` command to get all node_modules. Please suggest some solutions in this case. I am new to the app dev and still trying to learn.